# C++ binary tree segfault (implementation with class)

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

I've been trying to implement BST in c++ and I wrote these functions to insert new nodes in it. However, I am now quite stuck trying to understand why this code causes segfault. 
It probably has something to do with the fact that I'm not passing the address of root to my utility function because when I do, the insert functions start working properly. However, I do not understand why this particular implementation does not work. I would really appreciate if someone could clarify

```
class Bst {
    private:
        struct bstNode *root;
        struct bstNode* insertUtil(int, struct bstNode*);
        void delTree(struct bstNode**);
    public:
        Bst();
        ~Bst();
        void insert(int);
};

 /// struct bstNode *root = NULL;

struct bstNode* Bst::insertUtil(int x, struct bstNode *r){
    if(r == NULL){
        r = newNode(x);
    }
    if(x < r->data){
        r->left = insertUtil(x, r->left);
    } else{
        r->right = insertUtil(x, r->right);
    }
    return r;
}

void Bst::insert(int x){
    if(root == NULL){
        root = newNode(x);
        return;
    }
    insertUtil(x, root);
}
```

full code if you're interested: https://codepen.io/adrasti/pen/NWyVOZY

Comment: *However, I am now quite stuck trying to understand why this code causes segfault.* -- [What is a debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Think some more about what happens after `r = newNode(x);` in `insertUtil`.

Comment: In C++, you don't need `struct` tagging each `bstNode` identifier type.

Comment: Here we miss a lot of code to give an answer... try to use a debugger

Comment: You sometimes use the value `Bst::insertUtil` returns, and sometimes you don't. This is not healthy. Decide on one way to use a function, and apply it throughout the code. Why couldn't you write for example `void Bst::insert(int x){ root = insertUtil(x, root); }`? Or perhaps (a better interface) make `insertUtil` return `void` but accept `r` by reference?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. You’re right. I actually tried to write the “insert” function this way, but it doesn’t help to solve the issue. According to my limited understanding of how this code works, the one only way the “insertUtil” function returns anything other than the “root” itself is when is when I pass NULL as an argument to it. However, this case is covered by the “if” condition I have inside my “insert” function. Therefore, would it not be an extra assignment operation if I wrote it as in your example?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.  As for the latter part of your suggestion, I actually did try to make “insertUtil” accept the reference and it does solve the issue, as I stated in the original question. However, I’m really racking my brain trying to understand why the code I showed doesn’t work

Comment: @molbdnilo I create a new node with node->left and newnode->right equal to NULL and newnode->data equal to x and then pass its address to “r” inside “insertUtil”, right? Then this new address is being assigned to r->left or r->right from the previous function call, and all other function calls just repeat the already existing links in the tree… or so I think

Comment: It is not going to solve your issue, which you need to address separately. Use a debugger.

Comment: @segugio Why do you feel a need to insert anything into the empty subtrees of the newly created node? You already have anode with `x`, so your work must be done. (All you need to do to make it work is to insert `else` in one place.)

Comment: @molbdnilo I get it now, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a logic error.

this line(in `insertUtil`):

```
r = newNode(x); //no return
```

So, program will execute

```
insertUtil(x, r->left);
```

or

```
r->right = insertUtil(x, r->right);
```

and will alway execute:

```
r = newNode(x); //no return
```

never stop until out of memory.

I am also learning C++, and I hope to be corrected if I am not correct.

Comment: You were almost there :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please clarify why doesn’t “newNode“ have a return? Please note that “bstNode* newNode(int x)” is a function that I wrote, as can be seen if you go to the link to the full code I provided. I apologize I didn’t paste  some parts of the code directly, I thought the question would be convoluted if I did

Comment: @segugio I saw the implementation of `newNode(int)` function. myaybe it's not clear enough for me to describe, I means after execute `newNode(x)` in insertUtil, should return.As Patryk Gawroński answered.

Answer (score 0):

Definetly you miss break condition in `Bst::insertUtill` you can quickly by making small refactor in that function

```
struct bstNode *Bst::insertUtil(int x, struct bstNode *r)
{
  if (r == nullptr)
  {
    r = newNode(x);
    return nullptr;
  }
  if (x < r->data)
  {
    r->left = insertUtil(x, r->left);
  }
  else
  {
    r->right = insertUtil(x, r->right);
  }
  return r;
}
```

and after that change `Bst::insert` to

```
void Bst::insert(int x)
{
  insertUtil(x, root);
}
```

by doing that you will avoid stack overflow.

In case of searching of that you can add `-fsanitize=address` flag to gcc compiler or user `valgrind`

Also you can refactor code to be more C++ modern style but that I can paste you later

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please note that the problem that bothers me so is not a stack overflow, but a segmentation fault. I tried to implement the improvements you showed, but i think now the problem is that while a new node is being assigned to the  variable “r” inside the “insertUtil” function, the “root” remains unchanged, since “r” is only a copy of root. Therefore, the “root” never actually changes and no new nodes are inserted in the tree